# Print equals sign as a char

Tags: java, char

```
public static String dividerLine(char ch, int num) {
    String sum = "";
    for (int n=1; n<=num; n++) {
        sum += ch;
    }
    return sum;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(dividerLine('=', 40));
}
```

I am trying to get 40 equal signs to print out with this method.
Why does this code not work?

Comment: This code works fine. It does print 40 "=" signs. Instead of saying "Why does this code not work?" , try explaining what output/error you observed. Edit your question to include the output you're seeing.

Comment: Try to avoid `(int n=1; n<=num; n++)` unless it is necessary and use `(int n=0; n<num; n++)`. I know counting from 1 is more natural, but in programming it's really useful to get used to things starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuffer instead

```
public static String dividerLine(char ch, int num)
{    StringBuffer sum = new StringBuffer();
        for (int n=1; n<=num; n++)
        {    sum.append(ch);
        }
    return sum.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{    System.out.println(dividerLine('=', 40));
}
```

The good thing about StringBuffer is you can append any primitive data type and get a resultant string.